# Does the Livereload app work for .php files?

Tags: macos

I just found out about this Livereload app and browser extension which reloads the browser automatically when a code file is changed. Does this work for .php files as well? While trying out the installation, I could only options for .coffee, .haml etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about this  - http://livereload.com/, I'm pretty sure it only works on client side code (like CSS). PHP is run on the server, and the PHP executes every time you visit the page to generate the page. CSS doesn't have to do that, and the browser just looks at the CSS and applies the styling to the already rendered page. Livereload uses javascript to get the browser to apply the new styles.